# Use variable in filename with underscore

Tags: powershell

In my script I name an argument `$out` and then trying to use it in a filename like this:

```
c:/.../$out_date.txt
```

My problem is that `$out_` is recognized as "not only `$out`". The file name MUST be like this.
I already tried quotations or double quotations or `+` with no appropriate results.

Comment: `c:/.../${out}_date.txt`

Comment: I have made it! I thank you very much though!!!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Multiple options.

1. Use `{}` to qualify the variable name (as [pointed out by @PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37793050/powershell-place-variable-in-out-file-filename-i#comment63052361_37793050)):
   `"C:\folder\${out}_date.txt"`
2. Use the `-f` operator to expand `$out` before placing it in the string:
   `'C:\folder\{0}_date.txt' -f $out`
3. Use the backtick (`` ` ``) escape character to stop parsing of the variable name:
   `` "C:\folder\$out`_date.txt" ``
4. Use a sub-expression (`$()`) to evaluate the variable:
   `"C:\folder\$($out)_date.txt"`

Comment: I used #4. go figure. spent a long time trying to do what would be a simple concatenation in any other language.